# Help me with my Orbot's issue

Tags: orbot, android

I still can't figure why i can't connect to the tor network.

This is the log output:

```
checking binary version: 0.3.3.5-openssl1.0.2o
updating settings in Tor service
updating torrc custom configuration...
success.
Waiting for control port...
Set background service to FOREGROUND
Orbot is starting…
Orbot is starting…
updating settings in Tor service
updating torrc custom configuration...
success.
Orbot is starting…
Tor was unable to start: Error: 1 ERR= OUT=May 22 02:14:48.685 [notice] Tor 0.3.3.5-rc (git-81d71f0d41adf0d8) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2o, Zlib 1.2.7.f-linuxfoundation-mods-v1, Liblzma 5.2.3, and Libzstd N/A.
May 22 02:14:48.687 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
May 22 02:14:48.687 [notice] Read configuration file "/data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/torrc".
May 22 02:14:48.687 [notice] Read configuration file "/data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/torrc.custom".
May 22 02:14:48.698 [warn] Skipping obsolete configuration option 'WarnUnsafeSocks'
May 22 02:14:48.698 [warn] Skipping obsolete configuration option 'DNSListenAddress'
May 22 02:14:48.702 [notice] Scheduler type KISTLite has been enabled.
May 22 02:14:48.702 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
May 22 02:14:48.703 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
May 22 02:14:48.703 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
May 22 02:14:48.703 [notice] Opening HTTP tunnel listener on 127.0.0.1:8118
May 22 02:14:48.703 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:8118: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
May 22 02:14:48.703 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:0
May 22 02:14:48.703 [notice] Control listener listening on port 43045.
May 22 02:14:48.703 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
May 22 02:14:48.704 [notice] Closing partially-constructed DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5400
May 22 02:14:48.704 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
May 22 02:14:48.704 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:43045
May 22 02:14:48.704 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
May 22 02:14:48.704 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: "May 22 02:14:48.703 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:8118: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?" Something is already listening on 8118. Either it's Orbot or some other app. Try restarting your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off just the router leaving only the vpn on
Then click the exit button to exit app. Wait a few sec then open up the app again it should automaticly start up router with the vpn already still on. Then check debug log if it connects. if not repeat the process a couple more times until it does connect.